# Can't echo data from mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

For some reason I can't echo and data from my tables.

This is where i connect to the database "functions.php"

```
<?php

function connect() {

    mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("DBname");
}

function protect($string) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
}

?>
```

I then include this in my header

```
<?php

include("functions.php");
Connect();

?>
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    include("safe.php");
    ?>

    &raquo; <a href="main.php">Your stats</a>
    &raquo; <a href="rankings.php">Battle</a>
    &raquo; <a href="explore.php">Explore</a>
    &raquo; <a href="gym.php">GYM</a>
    &raquo; <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>      
    <?php

} else {

    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    Username <input type="text" name="Username">
    Password <input type="password" name="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">

    </form>
    <?php

}

?>
```

and this is my main.php where I'm trying to echo the data.

```
<?php 

session_start();
include ("header.php");


if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

    echo "You must be logged in to view this page";

} else {

    ?>

    <center><h1>Your stats</h1></center>
    <br /> <br />
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $User['Username']; ?></i></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Level:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Level']; ?></i></td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td>Attack:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Attack']; ?></i></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Defence:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Defence']; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Strength:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Strength']; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Will:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Will']; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cash:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo $Stats['Cash']; ?></i></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <?php

    }

?>
```

for some reason the echo parts won't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: Where are `$User` and `$Stats` defined?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Your `protect` function here is totally messed up, `addslashes` and `strip_tags` have no place being there. Just use prepared statements and you won't have to worry about things like that.

Comment: Learn PDO. May seem overwhelming at first but it is your friend. Also, where are the $user and $stats variables being defined. Im assuming your using fetch row?

Comment: Add your full code with `$User` and `$Stats` defined...

Comment: The `protect()` function is crazy... you can't just chain these escaping functions and it could actually have the opposite effect. Learn how to use the individual methods and in which situations.

Comment: You are not saving or reading anything from the database. This is why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PDO like the following code to connect to the database:

```
<?php
try 
{
    $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhostOrHostName;dbname=YourDatabaseName','YourUserName','YourPassword');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Then you can use the above connection for query data from the database like this:

```
<?php
    $ab = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
    $rs=$pdo->prepare($ab);
    $rs->execute();
    $result = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

The results fetched in $result can be then accessed as follows

```
<?php
     echo $result['column_name1'];
     echo $result['column_name2']; // and so on...
?>
```